# Show DetailRow on RowDoubleClicked Blazorise DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, blazor-server-side, blazorise

I use [Blazorise DataGrid](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/) component to show my master/detail data in which you click master row and DataGrid shows detail row/rows.

How can one use the feature of `RowDoubleClicked` and change the natural behavior of DataGrid, to show detail row/rows when the event fires?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visibility of detail row is handled by `DetailRowTrigger`. In the Blazorise demo for simplicity it is triggered only on selected row change, eg.

```
<DataGrid TItem="Employee"
    @bind-SelectedRow="@selectedEmployee"
    DetailRowTrigger="@((item)=>item.Id == selectedEmployee?.Id)">
```

To modify it to work with double click, you need to use `DetailRowTrigger` and save the selected id or item to a field so you can check for it within `DetailRowTrigger` handler.

```
<DataGrid TItem="Employee"
    RowDoubleClicked="@(e=>selectedIdOnDoubleClick = e.Item.Id)"
    DetailRowTrigger="@((item)=>item.Id == selectedEmployee?.Id)">
@code{
    private int selectedIdOnDoubleClick ;
}
```